# Incorrect Time.now - Not obeying Timezone Setting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, alias

Noticed that Time.now is returning the incorrect time (5 hours ahead of EST) ,even though it appears that the config is set to EST.

The only way that I've been able to get the correct EST is like this:

```
  #Ruby 1.8.7/Rails 2.2.2
  t = Time.now - (3660 * 5)
  est = t.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

  ### environment.rb
  config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
  config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'


  #### login_controller.rb
    @new_login_attempt.last_login_date = Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

    @new_login_attempt.save
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Time.zone.now` instead of `Time.now`

Comment: Tried it. Still off by 5 hours (t=Time.zone.now)